# How to correctly stop Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

Playing with data is a joy in Junyper/Datalab, but I do not want it to become costly.

[Google recommends](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/pricing):

> "You can minimize compute charges by stopping/restarting Cloud Datalab
>   instances."

However, if I stop the AppEngine instance or the Compute Engine VM instance, they simply restart ...

So how to correctly stop/pause Google Cloud Datalab, so that I'm only charged for my use, not for the idle time?
Is there some kind of trigger that restarts the instances?

Comment: _Google Cloud Datalab_ is currently in **beta**, so the problem discribed above is likely to disappear, or the solution might change in the future.

Comment: I have this problem too...If you delete the lab, then, I think you'll lose all your code. I think Google's documentation on the shutdown is incorrect. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues/742

Comment: @MikeChirico Thx for sharing the issue link. Deleting the datalab VM instance does not necessarily result in data loss [!]: The notebooks are in a git-repo (can be synced with Github/etc), and your raw data should only **temporarily** be stored inside the VM. Better options are Google Cloud Storage, BigQuery, ... But having to delete the VM instances is cumbersome and interrupts the flow of normal usage. 

[!] Try this technique first with non-vital data!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I'm doing. I like keeping everything in the cloud; but, I want to resume work with minimal fuss and cost.

**Save Data/Source and Delete Datalab**

**1.** **Commit changes to Your Cloud Git Repository.**  As long as the source changes are committed, they'll pop backup when you re-create google cloud. Keep your data in buckets  gs://... or BigQuery. Commit all changed Notebooks.

> [Your Cloud Git Repository](https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/browse?project=)

**2.** **Delete the datalab module.**

https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/appengine/versions?moduleId=datalab
[image]

**Resuming Your Work:**

When you're ready to resume your work, goto [launch cloud datalab](https://datalab.cloud.google.com/) sign-in, and deploy.  It will take 6 or 7 minutes. Once it's deployed, up, and running, you can go directly to your tree and resume your work. You're probably talking 10 minutes tops.

Comment: Thx @mike, I agree this 'best' solution at the moment. Although I hope Google will provide a more suitable solution in the near future.