# Unable to stop or delete datalabs environment on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I cannot delete the datalab using the instructions found: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started#manage_instances_and_notebooks under **Deleting VM instances**. Keep getting error --
"Error: There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again."

I keep trying after a period of time...but doesn't work. The charges to my account are growing and I cannot stop.

Already tried following: [How to correctly stop Google Cloud Datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800560/how-to-correctly-stop-google-cloud-datalab)

Comment: I believe you'll be able to delete them from AppEngine's Console at https://appengine.google.com/, although this workaround will not last as it is about to be shut down.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do...but I get the error above.  Tried dozens of times...but keep getting error.  Totally frustrating.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the link I've given? It should take you to the old AppEngine's console and not to Cloud Console

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted the entire project.